# Google Calendar API event always minusing one day

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

I am creating dict obj and sending it up to google calendar as with googles own example on their API documentation. I read a mssql database and then produce a csv file of the results. I then use the cdv information to write the events.

Snippets from my code.

```
def count_leaveduration(sdate, fdate):

try:
    date_format = "%Y.%m.%d"
    cmp_sdate = datetime.strptime(sdate, date_format)
    cmp_fdate = datetime.strptime(fdate, date_format)
    delta = cmp_fdate - cmp_sdate
    return delta.days, cmp_sdate, cmp_fdate
except Exception as e:
    input_logging('error', 'Cannot Count Leave Duration - Exception: %s' % e)

duration, sdate, fdate = count_leaveduration(line['FIRSTDAYOFABSENCE'],   line['LASTDAYOFABSENCE'])    
event['summary'] = '%s - Leave' % line['NAME1']
event['location'] = 'Out Of Office'
# date type here instead because all day event for duration.
event['start'] = {'date': '%s' % sdate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}
event['end'] = {'date': '%s' % fdate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}
event['attendees'] = [{'email': line['ELECTRONICMAILADDRESS']}]
appbuildobj.events().insert(calendarId=robj, body=event).execute()
```

The entries work fine in general but if the duration is longer than one day it seems to chop a day off on the calendar entry even though the date should be the finish date which is being presented to the calendar event dict. Of course the work around is to do something like this:-

```
fdate = fdate + timedelta(days=1)
```

However, Id like to know if anyone knows the reason for this happening?

Answer (score 4):

It's hidden but I've found it:-

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts

Such an event starts on startDate and ends the day before endDay. For example, a one-day event should have its start date set to day and its end date set to day + 1.

So I have fixed this with:-

```
fdate = fdate + timedelta(days=1)
```